# Harry Potter fanfic where Death Eaters find the Dursley's house but take pity on Harry after seeing how he lives

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I was reading this Tumblr post that said:

> Once upon a time I read a fan fiction (and I lost it), in which, according to the plot, the Death Eaters found the Dursley's house. But as soon as they saw how Harry lives, they literally took pity: "Damn bitch, you live like this?", they seized his house and began to carouse and have fun. Harry ran around the house and tried to save the property: "NO! This vase is an antique!", but he also had to bring them beer and snacks so that they would not walk around the house once again and accidentally break anything on the way to the kitchen.

Can anyone find this fanfic please?

Comment: You got to be really evil when even the Death Eaters pity the way you treat Harry 

Comment: "...huh" is all I have to say

Comment: I think this would make a great meme: Harry running around and saying "This vase is an antique!"